# Maximum tension in a rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

Lets say I have a siccative object that’s attached to a rope and it’s moving in a vertical circular motion around some circumcenter. If along the motion the rope will happen to reach maximum tension, intuitively it’ll tear, but will it?
If it’ll tear the object will proceed at the direction of its velocity?
Thanks for assuring that, and if it’s wrong thanks for correcting me

Comment: @sammygerbil absolutely not, not even close. The point of my thread is examination of the critical situation of maximum tension, the direction isn’t the main issue at all, just a side assuring question

Comment: Whether the rope breaks or not depends on the tensile strength of the rope & the force(s) applied, so it's not clear to me that there's an answer here, given what you stated.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum tension will occur at the lowest part of the motion as the both centripetal force and gravitational force act in the same direction. If the limiting force overcomes the maximum shear stress of the rope then it'll tear. And obviously the object will follow a parabolic trajectory due to the tangential velocity ( given at the instant of failure of the rope) and due to gravity.